# "Don't forget" event notification: how do they work?

Tags: facebook, facebook-events, facebook-notifications

I recently noticed that I received for some invitations, not all, a reminder notification saying "Don't Forget: X invited you to X event" on Facebook.

I wanted to know how these work, what is the rule or maybe function/button that drives these notifications?

My goal is to be able to use these and seed reminder notification to people that were invited but didn't respond.

Answer (score 2):

I could imagine that you can keep a list of all recipients and respondents. Any recipient not in the respondents list could be marked to receive a notification if they are still not on that list X amount of days before the event takes place.  This assumes that the respondents are a subset of the recipients. Here's a rough idea of how the pseudo...

Pseudo:

//all recipients 
recipients = [a,b,c,d..] 
respondents = [a,b]

if today is X days before the day of the event and 
                   respondents.length < recipients

```
       //send respondents  message 
       for each person  in recipients:
                if person is not in respondents:
                     person.send("Hey you, yeah you! check your event     
                      calendar!")
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to use this king of script with Facebook?

Answer (score -1):

No, [that answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/78923/354) was correct but completely useless unless you're a programmer at Facebook and you're going to code a new feature.

I know quite a lot of advanced stuff about Facebook but I haven't figured this one out either. The reminders probably aren't random, but the factors that cause it aren't obvious.

I would test the following:

- How close the event creator(s) is/are to you
- Number of days to event
- Whether you've ever actually visited the event, or just ignored (this is a good one)
- if you've RSVPd, and if so, what
- Whether your FB activity at the time of receiving the notification might indicate that you're looking for something to do.